# Android camera to display on Chromecast

Tags: android, streaming, webcam, chromecast

I have an Android phone with a camera. I would like the image from the camera to be displayed on my Chromecast, which is plugged in to a TV. ie using the phone as a webcam/IP camera.

This could be either streaming video, or photos, say updated every 20 seconds. This should not require an interent connection - the phone and Chromecast are both connected to the same wifi network.

So is there an Android app to do this? Preferably free of charge, but I may pay a few £ for a particularly good app.

Comment: Try [**this**](http://www.omgchrome.com/mirror-android-screen-tv-chromecast/) or [**this**](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-stream-local-video-from-your-android-to-your-chr-1654907042)